# GridView Checked Rows Values VB asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have GridView named GridViewTest and the first column in the GridView is a templatefield checkbox named CheckBox1. Im able to loop through all the rows that the GridView contains and display the value in a label named Label2. The issue i'm having is, I only want the rows that are checked to be displayed in the Label2. Can anyone help me?

> Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
>
> ```
>    Dim str As String = ""
>    For i As Integer = 0 To GridViewTest.Rows.Count - 1
>        str = (str + GridViewTest.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text & Convert.ToString(" >> ")) + GridViewTest.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text + " >> " + >GridViewTest.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text + "<br/>"
>    Next
>
>    Label2.Text = str
> ```
>
> End Sub

PS: This is VB ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewTest" runat="server" 
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
                       BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
                       CssClass="GridviewTable" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDetailGrid" EnableTheming="True" 
                       Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
                       Height="100%" PageSize="15" TabIndex="25" Width="985px" AllowPaging="True" EnableModelValidation="True">
                       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" CssClass="Freezing" Font-Bold="True" 
                           ForeColor="#FFFFCC" Wrap="False" />
                       <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                       <Columns>

                           <asp:TemplateField>
                               <EditItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                               </EditItemTemplate>
                               <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                               </ItemTemplate>
                           </asp:TemplateField>

                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn1" HeaderText="TestColumn1" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn2" HeaderText="TestColumn2" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn3" HeaderText="TestColumn3" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn4" HeaderText="TestColumn4" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn5" HeaderText="TestColumn5" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="TestColumn6" HeaderText="TestColumn6" />

                       </Columns>
                       <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="20" Position="TopAndBottom" />
                       <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" 
                           HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
```

Comment: Can you post the markup of gridview?

Comment: Use the code I have mentioned in my answer. Just replace the id of check box with the id you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a template field having a checkbox with an id of `CheckBox1`, then use the code below in the `Page_PreRender` event.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewTest.Rows

   Dim result As Boolean = DirectCast(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
   if result = True Then
      Label2.Text = string.Format("{0},row:{1} is {3}", Label2.Text , row.RowIndex, result);
   End If

Next
```

Comment: Im getting an error: Index (zero bases) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. Please help